# How to use RPC to judge whether a PKH is revealed?

Tags: rpc, reveal

I didn't find out from the RPC document how to judge whether PKH reveals or not.
I also try to get status from https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/account_status/ ,but i can't get what i want.
So how to use RPC to judge whether a PKH is revealed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ask the manager_key of the account : either it is a key_hash (not revealed) or a public key (revealed).

See this blog for an introduction to the RPCs for a basic wallet :

http://www.ocamlpro.com/2018/11/15/an-introduction-to-tezos-rpcs-a-basic-wallet/